# Echoing a backspace

Tags: bash, echo

Is it possible to echo a backspace in bash?

Something like

```
echo $'stack\b'
```

Shouldn't output `stac`? Or I'm missing something?

More specifically, I'd like to use that in:

```
ls | wc -l; echo $'\b items'
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`\b` makes the cursor move left, but it does not erase the character. Output a space if you want to erase it.

For some distributions you may also need to use `-e` switch of `echo`:

> ```
>   -e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes
> ```

So it will look like

```
 echo -e 'stack\b '
```

Also, `files=(*) ; echo "${#files[@]} items"`.

Comment: Hmm, and of course it's not possible to backspace on a new line, right? That's why my initial solution didn't work (I guess). Thanks for the nice solution to the files count. I'd give +2 if I could :-)

Comment: Why doesn't this method of deletion doesn't work for newlines?

Comment: `\b` goes back a single character, up to the left edge of the terminal. A newline is literally a *new line*, so the second line has its own left edge.

Comment: `echo -n 'test'` => no newline (that is "-n").

Answer (score 11):

So to answer the actual question about backspaces this will simulate a backspace:

```
echo -e "\b \b"
```

It will move the character back one, then echo a space overwriting whatever character was there, then moving back again - in effect deleting the previous character. It won't go back up a line though so the output before that should not create a new line:

```
echo -n "blahh"; echo -e "\b \b"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly what you're asking for, but also, in the line of Ignacio's answer, you could use for this case:

```
echo "$(ls | wc -l) items"
```

AFAIK you cannot print a character that deletes the one before, not even printing the char whose hexadecimanl number correspoonds to backspace. You can move back and print a blank space to delete, though. With **cput** you can do many things and print wherever you want in the screen.